# Centering Cards with Bulma CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, bulma

I'm currently building an application for a Pomodoro Timer, I'm using Bulma as a CSS Framework, and so far I'm loving it, I'm still learning how Flexbox works, I would like to know what would be the best approach to this situation and if it can be done using only Bulma classes or if I would have to create my own.

[image]

I'm trying to create "cards" for each task added, but I want them to be just about half or less that the full screen width. I don't understand how to make this happen using Bulma, since everything just takes the full width and I can't just center everything since it doesn't have a hard-coded width. This is my code for the section that contains the task cards.

```
 <div class="section">
     <div class="task-container is-center">
         <div class="card is-clearfix is-1-touch" style="margin-bottom: 10px" v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id">
             <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
             <span class="has-text-left">
                     {{task.desc}}
             </span>
             <span class="icon is-pulled-right has-text-danger"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></span>
             <span class="icon is-pulled-right has-text-primary"><i class="far fa-play-circle"></i></span>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Any help, tips, suggestions, etc. Would be greatly appreciated!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use columns classes to achieve what you want

```
 <div class="task-container columns is-multiline">
        <div class="card column is-half is-offset-one-quarter">
            // statements
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the link to the official documentation: https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/#centering-columns

You could wrap the `card` div with a `columns` container and use the `is-half` class if you don't want to use the offset class.

Comment: Woudl you say this is one of the intended uses for the `column` class? I din't try using it since when I think in using columns usually its for multiple columns on a single row, not a single column

Comment: I'm not aware of any classes in bulma other than `column` and its modifiers to specify the width of the div. If you need a single column in a row then you need to wrap it with `columns` and a `column` tag AFAIK. You could modify it with custom css properties with `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to `auto`

Comment: Seems like it, I'll stick to that approach then and maybe consider creating some helper classes for margins and things like that